# create new column based on values of another column in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset like these: df

| State | cancer | lifexp | health |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NSW | 0.003 | 81 | 95 |
| VIC | 0.005 | 85 | 95 |
| QLD | 0.003 | 81 | 93 |
| WA | 0.005 | 84 | 95 |
| SA | 0.004 | 83 | 92 |
| TAS | 0.002 | 80 | 91 |
| ACT | 0.005 | 82 | 89 |
| NT | 0.006 | 79 | 93 |

Now I would like to create a new column for the variables cancer, lifeexp and health.

i would like to create cancernew which gives values below the 0.004 the value 1 and values between 0.004 and 0.006 the value 2 and values above 0.006 the value 3.

For lifeexxpnew 1 for below 81, 2 for 81-83, and 3 for above 83

For healthnew 1 for below 92, 2 for 92-94, and 3 for above 94.

but I don't know how to do that

Comment: Is this pandas? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more concise way is to use `loc`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'State': ['NSW', 'VIC', 'QLD', 'WA', 'SA', 'TAS', 'ACT', 'NT'],
    'cancer': [0.003, 0.005, 0.003, 0.005, 0.004, 0.002, 0.005, 0.006],
    'lifeexp': [81, 85, 81, 84, 83, 80, 82, 79],
    'health': [95, 95, 93, 95, 92, 91, 89, 93]
    })

# cancernew column
df.loc[(df['cancer'] < 0.004), 'cancernew'] = 1
df.loc[(df['cancer'] >= 0.004) & (df['cancer'] <= 0.006), 'cancernew'] = 2
df.loc[(df['cancer'] > 0.006), 'cancernew'] = 3
df['cancernew'] = df['cancernew'].astype(int)

# lefeexpnew column
df.loc[(df['lifeexp'] < 81), 'lifeexpnew'] = 1
df.loc[(df['lifeexp'] >= 81) & (df['lifeexp'] <= 83), 'lifeexpnew'] = 2
df.loc[(df['lifeexp'] > 83), 'lifeexpnew'] = 3
df['lifeexpnew'] = df['lifeexpnew'].astype(int)

# healthnew column
df.loc[(df['health'] < 92), 'healthnew'] = 1
df.loc[(df['health'] >= 92) & (df['health'] <= 94), 'healthnew'] = 2
df.loc[(df['health'] >94), 'healthnew'] = 3
df['healthnew'] = df['healthnew'].astype(int)

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  State  cancer  lifeexp  health  cancernew  lifeexpnew  healthnew
0   NSW   0.003       81      95          1           2          3
1   VIC   0.005       85      95          2           3          3
2   QLD   0.003       81      93          1           2          2
3    WA   0.005       84      95          2           3          3
4    SA   0.004       83      92          2           2          2
5   TAS   0.002       80      91          1           1          1
6   ACT   0.005       82      89          2           2          1
7    NT   0.006       79      93          2           1          2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define functions for each case and use `apply()` to create the new columns.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'State': ['NSW', 'VIC', 'QLD', 'WA', 'SA', 'TAS', 'ACT', 'NT'],
        'cancer': [0.003, 0.005, 0.003, 0.005, 0.004, 0.002, 0.005, 0.006],
        'lifexp': [81, 85, 81, 84, 83, 80, 82, 79],
        'health': [95, 95, 93, 95, 92, 91, 89, 93]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def map_cancer(x):
    if x < 0.004:
        return 1
    elif x <= 0.006:
        return 2
    else:
        return 3

def map_lifexp(x):
    if x < 81:
        return 1
    elif x <= 83:
        return 2
    else:
        return 3

def map_health(x):
    if x < 92:
        return 1
    elif x <= 94:
        return 2
    else:
        return 3

df['cancernew'] = df['cancer'].apply(map_cancer)
df['lifeexpnew'] = df['lifexp'].apply(map_lifexp)
df['healthnew'] = df['health'].apply(map_health)

df
```

Output:

|  | State | cancer | lifexp | health | cancernew | lifeexpnew | healthnew |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NSW | 0.003 | 81 | 95 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | VIC | 0.005 | 85 | 95 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | QLD | 0.003 | 81 | 93 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | WA | 0.005 | 84 | 95 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | SA | 0.004 | 83 | 92 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | TAS | 0.002 | 80 | 91 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | ACT | 0.005 | 82 | 89 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 7 | NT | 0.006 | 79 | 93 | 2 | 1 | 2 |

Comment: I think your if-elif-else statement doesn't meet the requirement of the question. such as, in the fifth row of data, lifeexp is 83. If you follow the requirements of the question, lifeexpnew should be 2, but your result is 3.

Comment: Fixed, I was missing the "=". Thx

Answer (score 0):

Let's make it simple by removing unnecessary .000s .

CONDITIONS :

Health(H) :

1 if  H<92

2 if H == (92 to 94)

3 if H > 94

Life(L) :

1 if  L<81

2 if L == (81 to 83)

3 if L > 83

Cancer(C):

1 if  C<4

2 if C == (4 to 6)

3 if C > 6

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame as df
df = pd.DataFrame({'State': ['NSW', 'VIC', 'QLD', 'WA', 'SA', 'TAS', 'ACT', 'NT'],
                   'cancer': [3,5,3,5,4,2,5,6],
                   'lifexp': [81, 85, 81, 84, 83, 80, 82, 79],
                   'health': [95, 95, 93, 95, 92, 91, 89, 93]})
print(df)
"""
  State  cancer  lifexp  health
0   NSW       3      81      95
1   VIC       5      85      95
2   QLD       3      81      93
3    WA       5      84      95
4    SA       4      83      92
5   TAS       2      80      91
6   ACT       5      82      89
7    NT       6      79      93

"""

df['CANCER_new'] = pd.cut(df['cancer'], bins=[0,3,6,np.inf], labels=[1, 2, 3])
df['LIFE_new'] = pd.cut(df['lifexp'], bins=[0, 81, 83,np.inf], labels=[1, 2, 3])
df['HEALTH_new'] = pd.cut(df['health'], bins=[0, 91, 94,np.inf], labels=[1, 2, 3])

print(df)

"""
  State  cancer  lifexp  health CANCER_new LIFE_new HEALTH_new
0   NSW       3      81      95          1        1          3
1   VIC       5      85      95          2        3          3
2   QLD       3      81      93          1        1          2
3    WA       5      84      95          2        3          3
4    SA       4      83      92          2        2          2
5   TAS       2      80      91          1        1          1
6   ACT       5      82      89          2        2          1
7    NT       6      79      93          2        1          2

"""
```